# Force Bootstrap's collapsed navigation 100% height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So, I'd like to set the height of the collapsed navigation of bootstrap to 100% height.

e.g. https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ this should span over the whole screen.

I did some research and mostly found people using `height: 100vh;` but this is not dynamics, shouldn't matter too much in the end though, but I still don't like it.

Usually, one could e.g. do:

```
<div id="bar">
  <div id="foo">
    test
  </div>
</div>

html, 
body {
    height: 100%;
}
#foo, #bar{
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

But I'm asking myself now, what's the best approach to implement this when using bootstrap v3.

Comment: To have div height as 100% body needs to have 100% height which is not a practice..using view port height is the right approach here

Comment: so I should use height: 100vh;? So I'm asking myself then, how I can deactive scrolling when the navigation collapsed?

Comment: i am not clear about the part of making navigation deactive ...

Comment: I'd like to set overflow-x:hidden; so the user can't scroll anymore while the navigation is collapsed. I somehow fail listening to the proper event.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the Content while the Navigation is collapsed using JavaScript..
for example: `document.getElementById("ID").style.display = none;`

if there is no content under the Navigation, there is nothing to scroll... :P

Answer (score 0):

> So I'm asking myself then, how I can deactive scrolling when the navigation collapsed?
>
> I somehow fail listening to the proper event

As per your comment, I see the issue is that you dont get the proper point of the collapse. The plugin provides the events on `collapse`.

By bootstrap **[documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events)** this is how you do

```
$('#foo').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
})
```